# Linked List accessing private members ERROR C2248

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have made a linked list class of Employees here my code:

Node.cpp

```
#include "EmpNode.h"

    EmpNode::EmpNode(int id, string name){

        emp.id = id;
        emp.name = name;
        next = NULL;
    }
```

List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"
#include "Header.h"

bool ListOfEmp::insertEmp(int id, string name){

    EmpNode *newNode = new EmpNode(id, name);

    if (!newNode){
        return false; // Failure
    }
    else{
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return true; // Success
    }
}

bool ListOfEmp::findEmp(int id, const Employee &emp) const{
    EmpNode *currentNode = head;

    while (currentNode != 0){
        if (currentNode->emp.id == id){
            emp = currentNode->emp;
            return true;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Node.h

```
#pragma once
// My Node
class EmpNode {
    friend class ListOfEmp;
public:
    EmpNode(int id, string name);

private:
    Employee emp;
    EmpNode *next;
};
```

List.h

```
#pragma once
// My List of Nodes
class ListOfEmp {

public:
    ListOfEmp();
    ~ListOfEmp();
    bool findEmp(int id, const Employee &emp) const;
    bool insertEmp(int id, string name);

private:
    EmpNode *head;
};
```

Error   1   error C2248: 'Employee::id' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Employee' \\ 22  1   LinkedList

Comment: The error message is very clear. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You haven't posted the code for `Employee` but it seems that its members are private, at least the `id` member is.

Comment: Maybe you mean to construct the `Employee` from the `id` and `name`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to initialise the `emp` member using its constructor and that what you're looking for is

```
EmpNode::EmpNode(int id, string name) 
    : emp(id, name),
      next(NULL)
{
}
```